# How can I add another parameter to a drop down box?

Tags: c#, html, parameters

At the moment I have a drop down box which only displays a Suppliers Name with the value of the ID hidden behind it. I would also like to display the Suppliers account number next to the Supplier Name.

HTML:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.SupplierID,
    new SelectList(Model.Suppliers, "SupplierID", "SupplierName"),
    new { @id = "SuppNameDD", @class = "GRDropDown" }
)
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string client) {
    int clientID = clientRepo.GetClientIDByName(client);
    DashboardViewModel model = new DashboardViewModel();
    model.ClientID = clientID;
    model.ClientName = client;
    model.FinancialsAtAGlance = reportRepo.GetFinancialsAtAGlance(model.ClientID);

    model.SupplierID = -1;
    model.AccountNo = null;
    model.Suppliers = supplierRepo.GetAllSuppliersByClient(clientID);

    model.ReviewID = -1;
    model.AccountNo = null;
    model.Reviews = reviewRepo.GetAllReviewsByClientID(clientID);
    return View(model);
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class DashboardViewModel {
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<FinancialsAtAGlanceModel> FinancialsAtAGlance { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, decimal?>> Budgets { get; set; }


    public class SelectReport {
        public int ReportID { get; set; }
        public string ReportType { get; set; }

        public static IEnumerable<SelectReport> Reports = new List<SelectReport> {
            new SelectReport {
                ReportID = 1,
                ReportType = "Claims By Supplier"
            },
            new SelectReport {
                ReportID = 2,
                ReportType = "Department breakdown"
            },
            new SelectReport {
                ReportID = 3,
                ReportType = "Reason Code breakdown"
            },
            new SelectReport {
                ReportID = 4,
                ReportType = "Monthly Debiting report"
            }
        };
    }
    public List<SelectReport> allReports { get; set; }

    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }

    public int ReviewID { get; set; }
    public string AccountNo { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

How can add this is as the other value is a selected value and this is not what I want. It should be another datatext field.

Comment: Probably use string concatenation to show both Name and Account Number together.

Comment: Fair answer, however I am using a repository to get the data. I will update my post with some more code

Comment: @RazvanDumitru I would like the drop down list to look like so: "SupplierName" ("AccountNumber")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this display name is something that would be used multiple times, I would suggest adding a property to your `Supplier` class.  Something like `DisplayName`:

```
public class Supplier
{
    //...
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    //...

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return String.Format("{0} ({1})", SupplierName, AccountNumber); }
    }
}
```

Then, you just need to change your drop down list to use `DisplayName` instead of `SupplierName` as the text field:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SupplierID, new SelectList(Model.Suppliers, "SupplierID", "DisplayName"), new { @id = "SuppNameDD", @class = "GRDropDown" })
```

**EDIT:**
There is another way to do this that can be done all in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SupplierID, Model.Suppliers.Select(item => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = item.SupplierID.ToString(),
    Text = String.Format("{0} ({1})", item.SupplierName, item.AccountNumber.ToString()),
    Selected = item.SupplierID == Model.SupplierID
}))
```

Comment: Thanks, I may have to create another class because Im using entities directly related to my database

Comment: You can add properties to entity objects that don't relate to database columns.  Just add the `[NotMapped]` attribute.

Comment: @AndrewKilburn: Added another possible solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did use a slight alternative to your answer although it got me to where I needed to be

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can achieve your desired output by 1.create a custom helper with with extension method which will return MvcHtmlString which will create your custom HTML for dropdown and call that method in your view.

Like Below

```
public static class CustomDropdown
{
    public static string Dropdown(Priority priority)
    {       
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder ();
        sb+="<Select id='drop'>";
        for(int i=0;i<priority.name.length;i++)
        {
            sb+="<option id='dropop' value='"+priority.value[i]+"'title='"+priority.title[i]+"'>"+priority.name[i]+"</option>";
        }
        sb+="</select>";
        return Convert.ToString(sb);                   
    }
}
```

2.Bind the options of the given select with help of jquery like

```
var i=0;
$('.drpclass option').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('title',Model.priority.title[i])
    i++;
});
```